How To Re-Enter Data For A Specific Field - AND 'CR to act like TAB
ubuntu 22.04  python 3.12  pysimplegui 5
First Question:
All Fields are mandatory on my 3 Field screen. Using a mouse click, it is possible to bypass the AGE Field. Then SUBMIT is pressed.
I would then check to see that none of the Fields are NULL (empty). If I determine that the AGE Field (or any Field) is NULL, how do I go back and ask for it to be re-entered ?
Second Question:
If a Field is entered followed by a Carriage Return - is there any way to make it act like the TAB key and go on to the next Field ?
Thanks,
M....
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Name: ',tooltip='Name 3-31 Char'),sg.Input(default_text ="",enable_events=True,key='-NAME-')],
    [sg.Text('Age:    ', tooltip='Age 16-99'), sg.Input(default_text="",enable_events=True,key='-AGE-')],
    [sg.Text('Date:   ', tooltip='Date YYMMDD'), sg.Input(default_text="",enable_events=True,key='-DATE-')],
    [sg.Button("Update"), sg.Button("Exit")],
    ]
winx = sg.Window('Customer Data Entry', layout)

while True:                             # Indefinite Loop
    event, values = winx.read()         # Display Window & Wait for an Event
    if event == 'Exit' or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:  # Exit button or upper left X
       break

    if event == '-NAME-' :  # Name Validation
        print("Name Validation")

    if event == '-AGE-' and len(values['-AGE-']) and values['-AGE-'][-1] not in ('0123456789'):
       winx['-AGE-'].update(values['-AGE-'][:-1]) # delete last char from input
       print("Age Validation")

    if event == '-DATE-':   # Date Validation
       print("Date Validation")

    if event == '-UPDATE-':   # If no missing fields, Update to File
        # Check for missing fields - GO BACK AND ASK FOR SPECIFIC FIELD
        print("Update File")

        break

winx.close()

print('Field Values; ',values)


Refer https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/6741
